# Failed to Preview Report - Cannot find expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

So, I have a report and am getting the "Failed to Preview Report" error regards an expression.  I cannot find the expression it claims is erroneous - is there a simple way to find it?

My report has over 100 expressions and I have manually searched to no avail.

The full error:

> Failed to Preview Report
>
> The value expression for the textrun
>   'ID_gascombcountofallincl_.Paragraphs[0]. TextRuns[0]' contains an
>   error: [BC30198])' expected.

I cannot find anything relating to "gascombcountofallincl" in my report.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: OK so I managed to fix this by undoing a load of steps but no real idea what was wrong - is there a way to do a find or something in Report Builder to find the erroneous expression?

Comment: In Visual Studio you can find the text box under the Properties tab's list of items but the Report Builder doesn't have that feature. The only thing I can think of is to open the RDL in Notepad(++) and search for `ID_gas` to see where it is. It sounds like your expression has a syntax issue.